# LiveData.getValue() is not null but LiveData.observe is null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

I have a strange problem with my code.

**Scenario**...I have a list of data and I retrieve them in Viewmodel and observe from Fragment. When the first time I open my Fragment, everything works fine. But when I return from another Fragment, LiveData is not null. So I checked like this,

```
if(liveData.getUser().getValue()!= null){

//here getName() does not null and I get the value from liveData      

println(liveData.getUser().getName()) //this work
 
 liveData.getUser().observe(lifeCycleOwner(),
 Observer { user: User? ->{
  //Here LiveData is null
       }
     })

 }
 else{
         liveData.initiate()
         LiveData.getUser.observe(//same as above)
    }
```

I am observing in **onViewCreated()**. I don't know why LiveData.getValue() is not null but LiveData.observe return null.

Can someone help me with this?

**Edit**... This is my **UserViewmodel.class**

```
 class UserViewModel : ViewModel(){
       private var userLiveData : LiveData<User>?= MutableLiveData<>()
      fun initiate (){
          userLiveData = UserRepository.getUserData()
      }
      fun getUser() : LiveData<User>{
        Log.e("get called")
        return userLiveData
       }
 }
```

**Edit 2** This is my **UserRepository.class**

```
 class UserRepository {
     private var userData : MutableLiveData<User>?= null
     fun getUserData(): LiveData<User>{
          retrieveUser()
          return userData
     }
     fun retrieveUser (){
          val names = arrayOf("user1","user2","user3","user4","user5")
        for(name :String in names){
             user = User()
             user.setName(name)
             userData.value = user
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: post viewmodel here

Comment: I have added please check again.

Comment: You don't need to observe in `if else` , one time is fine, btw post `UserRepository`

Comment: I have added Sir. If I don't use     if else      , returning from another Fragment make the last observed value call twice. i.e. the last observed value get double on return.

Answer (score 0):

output

```
I/System.out: user1
I/System.out: user2
I/System.out: user3
I/System.out: user4
I/System.out: user5
```

**Simplified clean code**
Note: read code comments for understanding

**View** (Fragment or Activity)

```
val userViewModel: UserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserViewModel::class.java)
    userViewModel.getUser().observe(this, Observer {
        for (user in it) {
            println(user.name)
        }
    })
```

**ViewModel**

```
class UserViewModel : ViewModel(){
private var userRepository = UserRepository()
private var userLiveData = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<User>>()

//init block where initialise happens
init {
    //retrieve users and set in user live data
    userLiveData.postValue(userRepository.retrieveUsers())
}
fun getUser() : MutableLiveData<ArrayList<User>> {
    //observe user live date in view
    return userLiveData
}

override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    //clear live data
    userLiveData.postValue(null)
}
}
```

**Repository**

```
class UserRepository {
/**
 * retrieve users as ArrayList
 */
fun retrieveUsers (): ArrayList<User> {
    val names = arrayOf("user1","user2","user3","user4","user5")
    val list = ArrayList<User>()
    for(name :String in names){
        val user = User()
        user.name = name
        list.add(user)
    }
    return list
}
}
```

Comment: But when I come back from another Fragment, the last observed value get observed twice. So the output be like, `user5, user1, user2, user3, user4, user5`. The old last observed value get observed first and  then others get observed. And onCleared() never get called.I am using BottomNavigationView and Viewpager. I can't retrieve ArrayList, because data from room get retrieved one after another. Provided repository is sample.

Comment: How can I implement this? I have no idea on how to clear last observed data before observing next time.

Comment: maybe you can use Event object